# How to convert repeated values into columns in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am having one table that contain 3 columns named as ID,status,login_logout_time.

| ID | status | login_logout_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24456 | loggedin | 2022-01-03 10:00:00 |
| 24456 | loggedout | 2022-01-03 11:20:00 |
| 24456 | loggedin | 2022-01-03 11:30:00 |
| 24456 | loggedout | 2022-01-03 13:00:00 |
| 24456 | loggedin | 2022-01-03 13:30:00 |
| 24456 | loggedout | 2022-01-03 16:10:00 |
| 24456 | loggedin | 2022-01-03 16:20:00 |
| 24456 | loggedout | 2022-01-03 19:00:00 |

i want output like this

| ID | logged_in | logged_out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24456 | 2022-01-03 10:00:00 | 2022-01-03 11:20:00 |
| 24456 | 2022-01-03 11:30:00 | 2022-01-03 13:00:00 |
| 24456 | 2022-01-03 13:30:00 | 2022-01-03 16:10:00 |
| 24456 | 2022-01-03 16:20:00 | 2022-01-03 19:00:00 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select * except(grp)
from (
  select *, countif(status = 'loggedin') over(partition by id order by login_logout_time) grp
  from your_table
)
pivot (min(login_logout_time) for status in ('loggedin', 'loggedout'))
```

if apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]